# How to Apply maxLength to editable div using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I'm trying to simulate `maxlength` property to editable div using **react**, I have tried to enforce the length by triggering `keyPress` and check `innerText` size, then compare it to `maxLength`

Using this helper :

```js
function handlesInputMaxLength (event, maxSize = INPUT_MAX_LENGTH) {
  let text = event.target.textContent;
  if (text.length >= maxSize) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
};
```

```
             <span
                  contentEditable="true
                  onKeyPress={handlesInputMaxLength}
                  onInput={handleGreetingChange}
                >
                  {greetingMessage}
             </span>
```

It works when the user type, but it **fails** when the user copy & past the text, Also, I have tried to capture the text from `onPast` event, and I tried to pass the exact helper for `handlesInputMaxLength` but It keeps failing.

Any advice to handle this issue?

### Update(1)

My use case only depends on editable div to work with the below style, `input` and `textarea` are not usable options.

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make a state:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('')
```

define `MAX_LENGTH`:

```
const MAX_LENGTH = 10;
```

and on `onChange`:

```
<input
  value={value}
  onChange={e => value.length < MAX_LENGTH && setValue(e.target.value)}
  / >
```

Comment: Sorry, But I'm referring to a use cause where I should use only editable span or div

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using useRef hook and onKeyDown function

```
 let inputSin = useRef('')

 const keyPressEvent = (e) => {
   if (e.keyCode !== 8 && inputSin.current?.textContent?.length >= 140) {
   e.preventDefault()
  }
 }

 <div
    id="dropperble-id-e"
    contentEditable="true"
    ref={inputSin}
    onKeyDown={keyPressEvent}
  ></div>
```